# How to create weighted pie-chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
#Celltype   Weight
abTcells    10.65
Bcells  14.87
DendriticCells  22.71
gdTCells    8.6
Macrophages 7.14
Monocytes   6.43
Neutrophils 4.13
NKCells 6.94
StemCells   11.44
StromalCells    7.1
```

How can I use ggplot to to create the plot similar to the one generated by Excel below:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(1),y=Weight,fill=Celltype))+
   geom_bar(width=1,stat="identity")+coord_polar(theta="y")
```

[image]

Comment: If you want no axes nd with labels, let me know